# Update a VARCHAR2 column using a set of NUMBERS - how to force the decimal places?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have an update SQL looking like this:

```
UPDATE DCR_TEMP cr SET cr.TITLE = cr.AMOUNT||'/'|| cr.CLIENT_NUMBER;
```

This should update the `TITLE` column with, for example: `12223.52/1234567`

BUT, the data in columt AMOUNT can exist in 3 different versions, ie.:

1. 23
2. 23.1
3. 23.13

But it is required, that the AMOUNT should be converted to:

1. 23.00
2. 23.10
3. 23.13

There have to be two decimal places in the output, no matter which one of the 3. options of how the AMOUNT looks like.

How can I do this in SQL/Oracle?

Comment: What is the datatype of AMOUNT and CLIENT_NUMBER?

Comment: @SalmanA - AMOUNT is NUMBER, CLIENT_NUMBER is VARCHAR2.

Comment: @dziki I think Thorsten's answer is what you need. But you didn't accept it. Do you need more than that? What is wrong?

Comment: @FlorinGhita - couldnt accept it earlier cause of a meeting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to store data redundantly. If you can compute the title from amount and client_number, why store it at all?

However, numbers have no format. 23 = 23.0 = 23.00 = 00023.00000 . You'd use `to_char` to get a string containing the number formatted according to your wishes.

```
update dcr_temp set title = to_char(amount, 'fm9999999990D00') || '/' || client_number;
```